# SQL Query to Create Session ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DeviceID    TimeStamp          EventType
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00.000  Arrival Event
1   2020-01-01 01:00:02.000  Departure Event
1   2020-01-01 02:00:02.000  Arrival Event
1   2020-01-01 02:00:05.000  Departure Event
1   2020-01-01 03:00:05.000  Arrival Event
1   2020-01-01 03:00:05.000  ActivityI
1   2020-01-01 03:00:05.000  ActivityI
1   2020-01-01 03:00:19.000  Departure Event
1   2020-01-01 04:00:19.000  Arrival Event
1   2020-01-01 04:00:20.000  Departure Event
1   2020-01-01 05:00:20.000  Arrival Event
1   2020-01-01 05:00:20.000  ActivityI
1   2020-01-01 05:00:20.000  ActivityI
1   2020-01-01 05:00:30.000  Departure Event
1   2020-01-01 06:00:30.000  Arrival Event
1   2020-01-01 06:00:33.000  Departure Event
```

I have the above data. every event starts with arrival and ends with departure. i want to create sessionid/transactionid for every arrival. how do i do that in sql?

expected output

```
DeviceID    TimeStamp          EventType               SessionID
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00.000  Arrival Event                 1
1   2020-01-01 01:00:02.000  Departure Event               1
1   2020-01-01 02:00:02.000  Arrival Event                 2
1   2020-01-01 02:00:05.000  Departure Event               2
1   2020-01-01 03:00:05.000  Arrival Event                 3
1   2020-01-01 03:00:05.000  ActivityI                     3
1   2020-01-01 03:00:05.000  ActivityI                     3
1   2020-01-01 03:00:19.000  Departure Event               3
1   2020-01-01 04:00:19.000  Arrival Event                 4
1   2020-01-01 04:00:20.000  Departure Event               4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if there are two consecutive arrivals or departures?

Comment: Yes that's a possibility. Not sure yet how to deal with those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a window sum that increments by 1 for each arrival:

```
select 
    t.*,
    sum(case when eventType = 'Arrival Event' then 1 else 0 end) 
        over(partition by deviceID order by timestamp) sessionID
from mytable t
```

Comment: that works. is it possible to generate GUIDs instead?